# How can I use <p:uploadFile> with mode simple?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `<p:fileUpload>` to upload a file from my jsf page to a backing bean and getting following eror:

```
22:39:06,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "myweb.war"
22:39:07,341 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for mywebPU
22:39:07,399 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myweb.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myweb.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myweb.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2317) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1762) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory from [Module "deployment.myweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more

22:39:07,429 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "myweb.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myweb.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myweb.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myweb.war\""}}
22:39:07,433 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."myweb.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myweb.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myweb.war"

22:39:07,441 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myweb.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myweb.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myweb.war\""}}}}
22:39:07,818 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment myweb.war in 381ms
```

My jsf page:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:messages showDetail="true"/> 
                    <p:fileUpload value="#{admin_post.uploadFile}" mode="simple" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{admin_post.upload}"/>
                </h:form>
```

My web.xml: (The error occurs while using PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter)

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>51200</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
            <param-value>/tmp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>   
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: as the exception says: you need to add `commons-fileupload-xx.jar` to your classpath and also `commons-io-xx.jar`

Comment: Thanks your comment. I read Primefaces cookbook but not mention those files. I thought, those file had in jboss. i will follow your advice

Answer (score 0):

For those who didn't read comments:

Adding [commons-fileupload-xx.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi)
and [common-io-xx.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) to the classpath solved the problem perfectly.